# ActionMailer with Rails: uninitialized constant UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Getting this error in console when I try `UserMailer.welcome.deliver_now`

```
(irb):6:in `<main>': uninitialized constant UserMailer (NameError)

UserMailer.welcome.deliver_now
^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  UserMailerPreview
```

And before I was getting this NameError, the console was throwing the error that the method `welcome` was undefined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1EYI.png)

This is my file structure.

`app/mailers/application_mailer.rb`:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout "mailer"
end
```

`app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer  
  def welcome
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

`app/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb`:

```
<h1><%= @greeting %>,</h1>
<p>Example Email Body</p>
```

`app/user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb`:

```
<%= @greeting %>,

Example Email Body
```

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: Hi, you say this is at the console. Which console are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You say:

`app/mailers/application_mailer.rb`:

```rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout "mailer"
end
```

`app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`:

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer  
  def welcome
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

But that isn't true. Those files are in `app/views/mailers` according to your screenshot. Rails isn't able to autoload them properly. Move them to the correct location and try again.